# Pandas python Initializing groupby object with empty groups

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large dataframe. I want to groupby three columns in the dataframe, and then apply a function to each group. However, I'm also interested in some groups and keys that are NOT in the dataframe. How do I add those to the groupby object, so I may use `groupby.apply()` uniformly on all groups?

Comment: how about a merge and then groupby? can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would probably reindex after the fact:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 6], [2, 2, 9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

In [12]: s = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()

In [13]: s
Out[13]:
     C
A B
1 2  3
2 1  6
  2  9
```

For example, here s doesn't have results for (1, 1). We can feed in the "total" index with `MultiIndex.from_product` (or if you have it independently, feed in that):

```
In [14]: m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], [1, 2]], names=['A', 'B'])

In [15]: s.reindex(m)
Out[15]:
      C
A B
1 1 NaN
  2   3
2 1   6
  2   9
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks.